# is it possible to get signalr working with the javascript and page local(not loaded from server)

Tags: signalr

I try to make signalR work in a webview, but in order to get events from JS to show in my app, I can not load the source html file from the server. So I need to get hubs.js, jquery and signalr.js saved locally. But than how can I specify the connection to the server? Can I somehow specify the address of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the network address?
or
url address?

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://[insert url address here]/signalr;
$.connection.hub.start();
```